# enforce a Mongo collection to hold a single document only using Spring data mongo repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to enforce a Mongo collection to hold a single document only using Spring data mongo repository ? Is it possible via MongoRepository ?

Comment: I am wondering what is the use of such a collection. Not sure if we can do this for a nomal colelction. But can be done for a capped collection according to the docs.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/